# Performing HMAC with random key before MAC comparison

Tags: authentication, mac, hmac, timing-attack

In Laravel (a PHP framework) I can see that they calculate [a HMAC with a random key over the final HMAC before comparison](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.2.16/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L158). This additional HMAC calculation is of course performed for both the calculated MAC and the received MAC value, using this randomized key.

Does this just supply a method of performing a "constant time" compare? Or does it add other security properties to the MAC calculation. I presume the former, but I want to be sure. Is this a known technique for performing MAC comparisons?

Comment: I can't think of anything else it would add to the security properties.  Of course, there ought to be easier ways to do a constant time equality comparison; perhaps they are extremely paranoid about how "helpful" optimizing compilers can be.

Comment: @poncho I think it could be simpler than that; if there is no time constant comparison and there is a HMAC function it may be easier to use the latter. I'm not sure if the PHP type system would be a burden, but personally I don't see why a time constant compare wouldn't work.

Comment: I think http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-security-utilities implies that `StringUtils::equals` is already supposed to include protection against timing attacks. So there should be some other explanation for the additional HMAC layer?

Comment: I've seen suggestions to use this as constant time comparison by people who're afraid that the compiler will optimize the usual constant time comparison code into variable time code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/c3e6e84229f790077b9a2b43976d326f6ef12b24) that added this double HMAC only says it improves "valid MAC detection", but it simultaneously adds the constant-time comparison, so likely the reason is indeed defense against timing attacks:

> Improve valid MAC detection
>
> Implement constant time string comparison as well as double HMAC
> verification for encryption MACs.

Double HMAC is a [known technique](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30084/double-randomised-hmac-verification-to-prevent-timing-attack) to avoid the side channel attack, and [has been recommended](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/february/double-hmac-verification/) as a more reliable (and "simpler") alternative to constant time comparisons. I am not aware of anyone recommending *both*, which is pointless (they prevent the same attack) and costs even more than double HMAC - its main downside compared to constant time comparisons. On the other hand, it should not hurt, so perhaps it is done out of an abundance of caution.