# Double randomised HMAC verification to prevent timing attack

Tags: encryption, hash, hmac, timing-attack

A way to prevent timing attacks for hash string comparison is to perform additional HMAC signing in order to randomize the verification process (see [Double HMAC Verification](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/february/double-hmac-verification/)).

In addition to the second HMAC hashing for each hash, a random salt of random length is added to both in order to make the hashing timing / process even less predictable.

My PHP implementation of this look like this:

```
function hmac_verify ($hash_original, $message, $key) {

    $hmac_salt = '...'; // was added at the original HMAC signing
    $random_salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (rand(16,96));

    $raw_hash = hash_hmac('sha512', $message . $hmac_salt, $key, true);
    $hash_compare = base64_encode ($raw_hash); // $hash_original is in base64 
    $hash_compare_safe = hash_hmac('sha512', $hash_compare, $random_salt, true);
    $hash_original_safe = hash_hmac('sha512', $hash_original, $random_salt, true);

    if ($hash_compare_safe === $hash_original_safe) return true;
        else return false;

}
```

The function is called in this way after decrypting the encrypted text in order to verify the decryption result:

```
if (!hmac_verify ($hmac_hash, $plaintext . $cipher_text, $key . $iv)) return "HASH ERROR";
```

Will this successfully prevent a timing attack? Am I doing anything unnecessary? Could something be improved?

Answer (score 5):

> Will this successfully prevent a timing attack?

Strictly speaking you should be checking if [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) happens to be returning cryptographically strong numbers or not. If not, an attacker could guess be able to launch a timing attack practically as easily as without the extra HMAC.

<sub>(Got to love PHP... Even the function name: random "pseudo bytes"...)</sub>

You should also, if possible, HMAC the raw output rather than the base64. The base64 encoding function might itself even allow timing attacks (probably not but who knows), so you would be better off using the raw values. It is also faster.

> Am I doing anything unnecessary? Could something be improved?

The `$random_salt` is actually a key, so you should call it and treat it as such. You could reuse it across function calls, if you are after performance.

There is no advantage to generating a random-length key. You should be using a key size that matches the overall security strength you are aiming for, but e.g. 256 bits would be plenty.

The security of this relies on the security of HMAC. As long as the key is secret, no one will be able to learn anything about the original hash even if the final comparison leaked the value. And if the key is long enough it cannot be brute forced. Randomness does not help beyond generating a secure key.

Comment: Thanks. Openssl_random_pseudo_bytes is cryptographically strong (see e.g. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26206/should-i-use-urandom-or-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes). Can you explain why using a key of random length has no advantage over a fixed-length key, since it adds to the randomness of the string comparison?

Comment: @azenz, behind that link they use the same "strictly speaking" wording (by chance, I hadn't seen that before). I added some justification for why random length key won't help.

Comment: "The `$random_salt` is actually a key, so you should call it and treat it as such. You could reuse it across function calls, if you are after performance." I disagree; it should be treated a nonce so as to guarantee that the timing side-channel is blinded.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski, nonces are not secret. If you assume the adversary knows `$random_salt` they can brute force the HMAC just as if there was no blinding. On the other hand, reuse of the value does not lead to any attacks (that I can tell – correct me if I'm wrong of course).

Comment: `$random_salt` doesn't need to be secret, just unique. Reusing the value just moves the door: Instead of getting a timing difference in the original HMAC, you're getting it in HMAC(HMAC, static_key) which is just slightly more annoying to attack.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski, the original attack is that with $H(p, m)$ you can guess $p$ values, calculate the HMAC, find matching prefix through timing and eventually brute force the key/password (the latter is feasible to attack). If you compare $H(k, H(p, m))$ with a constant, public $k$, the attack becomes no more difficult, just an extra calculation step. If you compare with $k$ a public nonce that differs between each comparison the adversary gets less information, but is still able to rule out any $p$ for which the prefix differs sooner. With secret $k$, regardless of reuse, there is no attack.

Comment: (Also, if $k$ is public and predictable, the attack is again about as easy as with a constant $k$ or no blinding. So "nonce" is not a strong enough requirement, it would have to be a random value to reveal any less information.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I was in crypto stack exchange, and was briefly blown away by the formal mathematical expressions. :) -- Taylor and I discussed this in detail here: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/issues/21 -- the worst case for a random $k$ is the same as a static $k$, so it doesn't harm anything.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski the comments aren't really the place to discuss this. Maybe one of us should ask a new question about this?

Comment: There's also metzdowd, etc. if you think that would be a more appropriate venue.

Comment: I would intuitively agree with Scott in that a random nonce will be more helpful when it is uniquely generated for each hash comparison, but I am no expert, and don't understand mathematical explanations well :).

Comment: I've removed the second question from the question for obvious reasons.

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/preventing-timing-attacks-on-string-comparison-with-double-hmac-strategy